# How to deny user input by tying into text field ( input-group ) and allow input from the drop down list (input-group-btn )

Tags: php, mysql, edit

We use [phpipam](https://phpipam.net/).

We have found that if one enters data directly into the subnet field, the built-in CIDR calculations are not honored and an overlapping subnet can be input into the database.

We would like to deny user input, directly to the field while maintaing the architecture of the system and allow user input via the drop down list.

*The subnet edit page displayed in html*

[image: the subnet edit page displayed in html]

```
        <?php  if (!$showDropMenuFull){ ?>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input-w-200" name="subnet" placeholder="<?php print _('subnet in CIDR'); ?>"  value="<?php print @$cidr; ?>" <?php if ($readonly) print "readonly"; ?>>
        <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="input-group input-w-200">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input-w-200" name="subnet" placeholder="<?php print _('subnet in CIDR'); ?>" value="<?php print @$cidr; ?>">
                            <?php if (strlen($dropdown_menu)>0) { ?>
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-subnets">
                                            <?php print $dropdown_menu; ?>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `readonly` attribute to the `input`. It should prevent users to edit the `input` text, but scripts should continue being able to edit, and also it will be submitted in the form.

It will look something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input-w-200" name="subnet" placeholder="<?php print _('subnet in CIDR'); ?>" value="<?php print @$cidr; ?>" readonly="readonly">
```

You could also use `readonly` without value, but if you are using XHTML, remember that attribute minification is forbidden, so it must be complete.